# pass FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING

Tags: php, filter, mysqli

I have a this query:

```
$query="select * from news where news_id = (select max(news_id) from news where news_id< $id)";
```

for execute I use class. in this class

```
public function query($query) 
{
  $this->_query = filter_var($query, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
  $stmt = $this->_prepareQuery();
  $stmt->execute();
  $results = $this->_dynamicBindResults($stmt);
  return $results;
}
```

Is there any way that `<` signal is not filtered?

Comment: You may start from this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/14110189/285587 or this question in general http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, the whole idea is wrong. `FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING` won't help even slightest. Let alone it just breaks your SQL.

To protect SQL from injection you must use prepared statements. So instead of adding a variable directly to the query, add a question mark. And then put this variable into execute like this

```
public function query($query, $params) 
{
    $stmt = $this->mysqli->prepare();
    $types = $types ?: str_repeat("s", count($params));
    $stmt->bind_param($types, ...$params);
    $stmt->execute();
    return $stmt->get_result();
}
```

then just use it this way

```
$query="select * from news where news_id = (select max(news_id) from news where news_id<?)";
$data = $db->query($query, [$id])->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC)
```

Comment: Maybe you should `try` to `paraQuery()` and then catch an exception ?

Comment: Is it possibel  introduce me a book about use php and mysql in secure and correct way?