# How to automatically escape strings in a PHP SQL query?

Tags: php, sql, escaping, printf

Here's how I currently do it:

```
$db->query(sprintf('INSERT INTO pages (title, content) VALUES ("%s", "%s")',
    $db->esc($title),
    $db->esc($content)));
```

As you can see I'm manually escaping each string in the above query by passing each string to my $db->esc() method.

First let me indicate that I don't want to use prepared statements.

The best idea I can come up with is to have my $db->query() method wrap sprintf() and automatically call $db->esc() on each string conversion specification - like this:

```
$db->query('INSERT INTO pages (title, content) VALUES ("%s", "%s")',
    $title,
    $content);
```

That looks great to me, but now my question becomes how do I correctly parse out all the string conversion specifications from the format string and call $db->esc() on each respective argument(before passing that all to sprintf())?

Would you do it a different way?

Comment: Couldn't you just escape **all** input parameters? I assume this wouldn't break conform data (like numeric values etc.).

Comment: Any reason you don't want to use prepared statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should read about [prepared statement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement).

> Prepare: The statement template is created by the application and sent to the database management system (DBMS). Certain values are left unspecified, called parameters, placeholders or bind variables (labelled "?" below):

```
    `INSERT INTO PRODUCT (name, price) VALUES (?, ?)`
```

> The DBMS parses, compiles, and performs query optimization on the statement template, and stores the result without executing it.
>      Execute: At a later time, the application supplies (or binds) values for the parameters, and the DBMS executes the statement (possibly returning a result).

And it's implimentation in PHP: [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php), [MySQLi](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php), [PostgreSQL](http://www.php.net/pg_prepare) and other. So, there is no reason to implement it by yourself. Just use it.

Answer (score 1):

First let me indicate that you **want** to use prepared statements.
The very automatic "escaping" (although it have to be called *formatting*) you are talking of, is what exactly prepared statements are for.
Prepared statement is not necessarily have to be based on a database-supported native prepared statement. The general idea of prepared statement is to represent some query part with placeholder and to apply some formatting when replacing a placeholder with actial data. So - your approach is already using placeholders AKA prepared statements.

But there are some important things you missed

- whatever "escaping" can do **nothing** good. **Proper formatting** have to be applied instead
- proper string formatting require either quoting **and** escaping, and thus your prepared statements handler ought to apply both.
- there are **more than one** different SQL literals, each require **different** formatting. So, to meet the real life requirements, you can't rely on a single `esc()` function

So, here you go - [the code for such a wrapper you're asking for](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14178129/285587) , which does **correct** formatting, and thus you will have your queries no less secure than with PDO. Although with all the limitations which PDO has.

So, if you want to properly format **everything**, that may may be added to the query, you will need another wrapper, a more complex one: [safeMysql](https://github.com/colshrapnel/safemysql)